# Determine Springs bean instantiation order in Grails 3.3 with GORM 6.1.x

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot, grails-3.3

I am using a Grails 3.3 application that uses GORM `6.1.6.RELEASE`, Spring-Boot `1.5.4.RELEASE` and Spring Core `4.3.9.RELEASE` behind the scene. I am trying to declare a Spring bean that get initialized just before Hibernate starts to validate the underlying database schema.

Here is what I like to do. I want to register my Flyway as a Spring bean and inject the `dataSource` bean into it. In order to have Flyway run before Hibernate starts to validate the current database schema, I add my `flyway` bean as a dependency onto the `sessionFactory` bean. The order would be as follows:

1. `dataSource` bean
2. `flyway` bean
3. `hiberateDatastore` bean

GORM 6.1 uses `org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore` as a Spring bean to initialize the Hibernate ORM and the database. The `sessionFactory` bean declares the `hibernateDatastore#getSessionFactory` as factory class. 
Therefore the `hibernateDatastore` always is created first.

What is the way in Grails 3.3 to create a custom Spring bean that has to run after the connection to the database is available but before the Hibernate stuff gets initialized?

In previous versions of Grails 3.x it was possible to declare it in `resources.groovy` like this.

```
beans = {

    if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
        flyway(Flyway) { bean ->
            bean.initMethod = 'migrate'
            dataSource = ref('dataSource')
            locations = 'classpath:db/h2'
            baselineOnMigrate = true
        }

        BeanDefinition sessionFactoryBeanDef = getBeanDefinition('hibernateDatastore')

        if (sessionFactoryBeanDef) {
            def dependsOnList = ['flyway'] as Set
            if (sessionFactoryBeanDef.dependsOn?.length > 0) {
                dependsOnList.addAll(sessionFactoryBeanDef.dependsOn)
            }
            sessionFactoryBeanDef.dependsOn = dependsOnList as String[]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Grails issue https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails 3.3.0 changed the mechanism of the `dataSource` bean creation. The Grails project lead stated in the related [issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10769):

> Previous versions of Grails created the dataSource bean separately from the session factory. We would need to restore this behaviour I guess so the dataSource can be referenced without triggering the creation of the sessionFactory

After upgrading to Grails 3.3.1 the `dataSource` bean is again available before the session factory gets created. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Spring provides a visualisation of a 'bean instantion tree' however you could set the log level for `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory` to `DEBUG` and you'll get output like this:

> Creating shared instance of singleton bean '...fully qualified class name...'
>
> Returning cached instance of singleton bean '...fully qualified class name...'

You could review this log output for beans from the Hibernate namespace.

I presume you'll use the results to declare a `DependsOn` relationship so just for completeness this would look like:

```
   @Bean 
   public SomeHibernateClass createHibernate() {
       ...
   }

   @Bean
   @DependsOn("createHibernate")
   public MyClass createMine() {
       ...
   }
```

Comment: thank you for responding. Sorry my question was not very accurate. I have updated it. Your hint with the logging proofed that the HibernateDatastore always is the first in line. And there is no other obvious bean that I could use before the datastore.